# How to get Results for SELECT ... IN (...) which not match IN() clause

Tags: mysql

I have an array of ids (e.g. 1,4,7,8,9) and a table example with id field. (values of ids in the table 1,4,8,9,10) 
I want to get the ids of the array which are not used in table, so actually the opposite of

```
SELECT id FROM example WHERE id IN (1,4,7,8,9);
```

So the result I expect here is 7 as it is the only value of array 1,4,7,8,9 which is not used in the table.

Can someone please tell me how I can realize that query?

BR
Forfaro

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You can create a temp table with the values which you want to search and then use `not exists`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a temp table with the values which you want to search and then use `not exists`.

**Query**

```
create table #t(`id` int);
insert into #t values
(1), (4), (7), (8), (9);

select `id` from #t t1
where not exists(
     select 1 from example_table t2
     where t1.`id` = t2.`id`
);

drop table #t;
```

Comment: Hoped to get away without temp table in a simple query :-) But solved it that way by temp table now. Thx for help!

Comment: Just for interest: Following query works, but it's not so nice and I bet not very performant, but it also did the trick (unfortunately a little bit late :-) ):

`select * from  
    (select 1 as id union
     select 4 as id union
     select 7 as id union
     select 8 as id union
     select 9 as id
    ) as ids
WHERE id not in (
select id from example` 
);

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of

```
SELECT id FROM example WHERE id IN (1,4,7,8,9);
```

can be achieved by negating the condition in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT id FROM example WHERE id not IN (1,4,7,8,9);
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM example WHERE not (id IN (1,4,7,8,9));
```

Comment: But that gives me the 10 in my example as it is the only id in the table which is not in 1,4,7,8,9, so it's unfortunately not what I need.